# How to add json files to grunt build?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm creating angular project and I have few dictionaries in json files.
When I'm building them with grunt and deploying on server I'm getting errors when my service is trying to get those jsons.

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/dist/scripts/dictionaries/loanStatuses.json"

I started my project with yeoman.
I didn't change my grunt config - I don't really know how to.
How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Gruntfile.js, search the copy configuration and add this to the files.src array:

```
'/scripts/dictionaries/*.json'
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working.

Could you tell me where can I find good source for learning how to configure those things?

Comment: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy -> Here you have the documentation for the grunt-copy script.. If you look in your package.json you can see what Yeoman pre-installed and you can search documentation for each plugin